# Ssh and nginx takes 15 mins to load/ start | Google compute engine?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Every time I stop and start my VM instance, I cannot connect to it via ssh and web application not accessible, Have to wait 15 mins. We have a static IP.

Also created a snapshot and created a new instance from it and reconfigured ssh via gcloud but once I turn it off and turn it on the back, I cannot access until 15 mins after VM successfully starts

I have checked all firewall setting, and all seems ok. Sometimes I have to disable/ enable http /https. Also reconfigured ssh keys.

I just have to wait 15 mins after the VM starts.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This where it gets stuck ...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Name Resolution.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Wait for Network to be Configured.
         Starting Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)...

Comment: The issue seems related to the bug in the OS:Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1010-gcp x86_64)

4.15.0-1010-gcp
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Comment: More details on it : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111079563